# Nativescript app to receive data from local browser without using a server

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

We have an angular web application that can go offline using service workers. Most of the time it's used offline than online.

To print a few info to a portable bluetooth printer (like a receipt), we've created a nativescript app that looks in the downloads folder for files downloaded from the web app. (NB: At the moment we only intend to support android devices. Converting the web-app into nativescript is also out of the question due to time constraints)

This works but maybe it's not the best way to do it. We would like to know if it's possible to let our nativescript app listen for data from the browser without using an api server in between them.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the stored information you could use [`application-settings` module](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/application-settings) or some local database like SQLite ([nativescript-sqlite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-sqlite)) or even locally store the info with Firebase Realtime Database (and the enabled offline mode in the `init` as discussed [here](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/DATABASE.md))